# How to ask for input in nasm

Tags: nasm

I want to make a program that asks user for input number and calculates factorial of it. This is what I have so far:

```
; use function recursion to find the factorial 3
; Fact (n) = n * fact (n-1) for n > 0

section .text
global _start

_start:

mov    bx, 3        ; 3 is the factorial limit
call    proc_fact
add ax, 30h
mov    [fact], ax

mov    edx, len    ; print message
mov    ecx, msg
mov    ebx, 1
mov    eax, 4
int    80h

mov    edx, 1        ; print factorial
mov    ecx, fact
mov    ebx, 1
mov    eax, 4
int    80h

mov    eax, 1        ; exit
int    80h

proc_fact:
cmp    bl, 1        ; a loop to calculate the factorial next number
jg    do_calculation
mov    ax,1
ret

do_calculation:
dec    bl        ; decrement bl by one to use for next number (n-1)
call    proc_fact    ; process next factorial
inc    bl        ; increment bl by one to use for next number (n)
mul    bl        ; ax = al * bl
ret


section .data
msg db "factorial 3 is: "
len equ $ - msg

section .bss
fact resb 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using nasm for 32-bit x86 Linux. In this case you probably want to load input from STDIN using read syscall.

The code would be something like this:

```
mov eax, 3     ; read syscall number
mov ebx, 0     ; STDIN file descriptor
mov ecx, fact  ; buffer to store input
mov edx, 1     ; number of bytes to load
int 80h
```

In this example the number is loaded into `fact` but you might want to make a separate buffer in `.bss` for it.